How reusable Popper button in MUI
I have customized the following code for the MUI Popper component. The content that opens through the popper is now dynamic. How can I also make the button dynamic so that I can use it for other parts as well, such as filters and search?

import * as React from "react";
import Popper from "@mui/material/Popper";
import user from "@/public/user.svg";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function SimplePopper({ children }) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popper" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        aria-describedby={id}
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
        className="flex items-center gap-x-2 rounded-lg  lg:rounded-xl border border-[#d2d1d3] lg:py-2 lg:pl-3 lg:pr-8 px-3 py-2 "
      >
        <Image src={user} alt="" className="" />
        <span className="pr-2 max-lg:hidden">User name</span>
      </button>
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
        {children}
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}

Because of the presence of id and onclick in the button, I cannot do this easily.

You can create a reusable button component using props in ReactJS.
Props let you pass data between parent and child components.
So, creating a <Button /> component could look like this
const Button = ({ children, id, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      aria-describedby={id}
      className="flex items-center gap-x-2 rounded-lg  lg:rounded-xl border border-[#d2d1d3] lg:py-2 lg:pl-3 lg:pr-8 px-3 py-2 "
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;

Then use it in your component like this:
import * as React from "react";
import Popper from "@mui/material/Popper";
import user from "@/public/user.svg";
import Image from "next/image";
import Button from "./button"; //replace with correct import file path

export default function SimplePopper({ children }) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popper" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Button id={id} onClick={handleClick}>
        <Image src={user} alt="" className="" />
        <span className="pr-2 max-lg:hidden">User name</span>
      </Button>
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
        {children}
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}

Let me know if that helps or if you have any other questions.

The exact problem here is that the second code you wrote is a component itself that is supposed to be used elsewhere. Converting the button into a component won't solve the problem.

Okay, I see. Is there an issue with using props for the id and onClick via the code you're trying to make its own component?

Yes, the problem here is that the content of the button is supposed to be used for other places, such as pop-up for search and filter, but now it is only used in this component to open the user.
